# Why aren’t these two `<p>` and `<h3>` elements vertically aligned?

Tags: html, css

I wrote this code, also available on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndresJCremades/nexws3z9/6/#&togetherjs=hSS4EdFVCC):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Not spacing to top and bottom and auto spacing to left and right*/
  padding: 0 20px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3,
p {
  max-width: 80ch;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome! <span>I'm glad you're here.</span></h1>
    <h3>My name is Andrés-J. Cremades, and I'm an Interaction/UI Designer.</h3>
    <p>Usability obsessed interaction designer. Building a UX Designer career founded on strong technological knowledge. Creative and perfectionist by nature with a particular interest in graphic design and HCI with proven working team skills.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I don't understand why the `<p>` and `<h3>` elements aren't aligned vertically ***when the browser window is expanded completely***.

The thing is that I set a maximum text width of 80 characters and to center it I wrote this first and it worked:

```
p {
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 80ch;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then I wanted the `<h3>` element to be vertically aligned with the new position of `<p>` so I modified the code like this:

```
h3, p {
  max-width: 80ch;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: auto;
}
```

I tried to set a `margin-left` value for `<h3>` and it worked. Why `margin-left` and `margin-right` set a `auto` don't work on `<h3>` as on `<p>`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be an issue with your max-width in ch.

Comment: @FabioManzano is right. `80ch` is a [font-relative length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), resulting in a different `max-width` for those elements - affecting your `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto` results.

Comment: Bingo! I used `px` instead of `ch` and it works. Thank you very much, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As users @FabioManzano and @benvc pointed (*see comments under the question*), the problem is this declaration:

```
max-width: 80ch;
```

> **80ch** is a font-relative length, resulting in a different `max-width` for
>   those elements - affecting your `margin-left: auto;` and
>   `margin-right:auto;` results. [@benvc]

I want to limit text lines length under 80 characters but I had to find another way to do it.

I read the recommendations from [this article](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability) about how to set a text line length limit properly, and I used `px` instead of `ch`. Now they are vertically aligned:

```
h3, p {
  max-width: 504px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```